# Customize toolbar of VLC

Tags: vlc

On Windows/Linux, it's really easy and straightforward to customize the VLC toolbar by using the menu "Tools">"Customize Interface..." [(See this help page.)](https://www.vlchelp.com/how-to-customize-interface/)

Somehow this menu doesn't seem to be available in macOS.

Is it just a missing Mac functionality, or is there a way to customize the buttons showing on the toolbar on macOS?

Comment: This may be a good question for feedback to VLC support. [Support Contact](https://www.videolan.org/contact.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is indeed missing functionality. You can add (but not change the positions of) some media play buttons like Previous, Next and Show Equalizer to the interface toolbar using `Preferences`... under the VLC Menu. Clicking the `Show All` button which appears at the lower-left corner of the `Preferences`... window will enable a great deal of additional customization, but it's challenging to anticipate or even recall which features are available in Basic, Show All, or both modes.

I'll alert you to a potential hazard: It's mandatory to save any changes you make to VLC's prefs before moving from one preference area to another, much less between `Basic` and `Show All` modes. Otherwise, your changes won't be retained--and there's no warning this is the case. Plus, annoyingly enough, the prefs window closes when you do save your changes, and re-opening it always opens in Basic mode. Furthermore, changing an item in one mode can cause changes to occur to seemingly unrelated items present the other, unseen mode--again, without warning.

Also, as far as I know (unless a recent nightly build has re-enabled the option), skins aren't customizable in MacOS and haven't been for years. Oh, here: Let me save you ten minutes of wandering around clicking disclosure triangles looking for the additional media buttons for the toolbar in the Playlist. They're here: `Preferences ▸ Show All ▸ Interface ▸ Main Interface ▸ macosx ▸ Appearance`

Mind you, if you're determined enough, the `Main Interface` section is also where you would go to run VLC on a homebuilt `Lua` or `ncurses`  interface--and put your buttons wherever you please.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. That's a shame the option isn't available though.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the skins, there is no way to customize the interface in Mac using the Application provided (Other than the options available in preferences).